# Scrolling to expanded DIV problem and links in expanded box

Tags: jquery, scrollto

I'm working on the code for my new portfolio site and I'm using masonry for the expanding grid layout.

I'm having problems with the code that makes it scroll to the expanded DIV. It doesn't always scroll to the upper part of the div .expanded... Here's a sample:

http://bit.ly/axDQox

Try to click box 1 and then box 5. You'll notice that the page scrolls to half-way below box 5. It took me hours to get the scroll-to expanded box working, I'm not really that good in jquery, so help will really be appreciated. :)

Another thing, if you expand box 1 and click on the link, box 1 closes.

I got the sample html/css code from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030199/help-with-jquery-masonry-plugin-how-to-expand-collapse-boxes-to-reveal-content) by the way.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `scrollTo` function is being called before the animation is finished. The jQuery `animate` function has a callback just for this reason (you are actually already using it).

```
.animate({
  width: size[0],
  height: size[1]
  }, function(){
  // show hidden content when box has expanded completely
  $(this).find('.expandable').show('slow');
  $(this).find('.hideable').hide('slow');
  $('#grid').masonry();
  // call scrollTo here
});
```

I just realized that you have other animations going on at the same time, so this won't work completely. Maybe Something on the jQuery [Effects](http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.2/Effects) documentation can help you - specifically the [queue/dequeue](http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.2/Effects#.queue.28.29_.2F_.dequeue.28.29) parts.

Comment: Ok I've got it working. I had to do a lot of revisions in the code. Also had to remove the animation which causes the scrollTo problem. Now I have integrated easySlider but I'm having problems resetting it back to preinit mode so I can call it again using a new slider ID. 

Here's what I've accomplished so far http://keanetix.co.cc/folio2010

If you notice when you click Box#1 (CM Partners) then click Box#3 (NBCM), the slider doesn't work. Help please? Thanks. :)

Comment: I think that is because of the size of the actual page. If a make my browser very "short", I believe it scrolls as you intended. Also, if the page had more content below this area it should scroll properly. On my browser, it just scrolls to the bottom, which I think it should.

Answer (score 0):

It's almost working using the queue function. However, when another box expands, the previously expanded box won't restore/close. I'm using this code for [this](http://keanetix.co.cc/newsite/index.htm) page:

```
.animate({
 width: size[0],
 height: size[1]
 }, function(){
 // show hidden content when box has expanded completely
 $(this).find('.expandable').show('slow');
 $(this).find('.hideable').hide('slow');
 $('#grid').masonry();
 // scrollTo here
 $(this).queue(function(){
 var yloc = $('.expanded').offset().top;
 $(document).scrollTo( $('.expanded') ,600 );
 //next();
 }
 });     
 });
restoreBoxes();
$(this).addClass('expanded');
```

If you notice the "next()" function is commented. If I uncomment the "next()" function, the previously expanded box closes but the page won't scroll correctly to the expanded box. It scrolls about 100px more.