# jQuery masonry and expanding boxes animation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-masonry

I'm doing a site with a page that shows boxes (all the same size) with some content (video + text) that expends on a `click()` event. The page is using **masonry** to reorganize the boxes once one opens or closes. This page is heavily based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030199/help-with-jquery-masonry-plugin-how-to-expand-collapse-boxes-to-reveal-conten), where **fudgey** provided [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FS34t/).

It almost works 100% fine in my case but i have an animation bug when the box expands. It seems that the box does expand, retracts itself a bit and expands for good. All of this in a matter of seconds. The page is running with worpdress to load the posts and also uses [scrollTo](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) to scroll the window to the right position after a box's expand and vimeo' api to have an external control of the videos in the boxes.

I've set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinch/PS9vx/) to replicate the behavior. I noticed that if i comment this line: `$('#grid').masonry();` in the **animate** of the `$('.box').click(function(){` it does work fine, but kills the reorganisation animate of course.

I'm pretty sure the solution is very close but i can't seem to nail it.

A live demo of the site can be [seen here](http://kevinchevallier.com/dp2012/).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, it was not a javacript problem in the end but a css bug! Came from the `.wrap` div that was not tall enough to show the content. I've updated the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PS9vx/1/).